# What is this inductor symbol? Straight line with 90° and 45° intersection lines

Tags: inductor, schematics, symbol

In the picture below, what does the symbol labeled with "L11" stand for?

The letter L and the 10uH suggest it is some kind of inductor, but the symbol seems rather non-standard to me.

[image: unidentified schematic symbol L11]

Comment: 10uH is a bit high to be a track. Maybe adjustable? Maybe it's just a non-standard symbol for an ordinary inductor. What are the symbols used by the other inductors on the circuit?

Comment: @Neil_UK: this symbol is used for almost all inductors in the schematic. If specified, the values are always in the uH range. There are two exceptions: a 10 mH inductor which is drawn with the standard coil symbol, and a variable air core transformer with center taps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the symbol of an **iron core with winding**, resulting in an inductance of \$10 \mu H\$.

Source:

[image: Ferric core symbols]

Comment: I've never seen any of these symbols before. What standard are they from?

Comment: @Felthry I'm not sure, but it probably is from a [non-standard standard](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/standards.png). And because it looks fairly incomprehensible, I'll guess it's an European symbol (we're like this here, you know).

Comment: Could be power/high voltage electronics standard. I've seen them use quite different symbols on quite a few occasions. I would be staring at a schematic and then the designer would say "so you can see the switch on this shield conductor" and I'd go "Ooohhh so that's supposed to represent a switch"

Answer (score 1):

Back when, those used to be used widely to create [memory arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic-core_memory).

[image]

**A 32 x 32 core memory plane storing a whopping 1024 bits of data.**

[image: Up Close]
**Up close**

In fact, a company where I worked was still knitting them for the military back in the early 90s. They are probably still using some.

Comment: Surely those parts would have four connections shown on the symbol?

Comment: I'm glad they're obsolete, but man are they gorgeous!